# How I could fix this error with SQLalchemy? Does the problem only in SQL code maybe there is something else?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Bellow there is a code which suppose to let me add a book and added book see in route /books, however it gives me an error:

```
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 3 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO book (book_name, book_author, publication_date, "ISBN_num", description, img, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Robbins Basic Pathology, 10th Edition ', 'Vinay Kumar & Abul K. Abbas & Jon Aster ', '2017-05-01', Decimal('9780323353175'), "Part of the trusted Robbins and Cotran fami
ly, Robbins Basic Pathology provides a readable, well-illustrated and concise overview of the principles o ... (185 characters truncated) ... ew artwork and more schematic diagrams to
further aid in summarizing key pathologic processes and expand the already impressive illustration program.", <FileStorage: 'book1.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>, 49.49)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

Here is my flask code, it is my first time with a flask and actually it might have more errors, however I want to complete specific problem up there.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileRequired, FileAllowed
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, DateField, TextAreaField, FileField, FloatField, DecimalField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '8BYkEfBA6O6donzWlSihBXox7C0sKR6b'
Bootstrap(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///books.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Book(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    book_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    book_author = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    publication_date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    ISBN_num = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text(400), nullable=False)
    img = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)


db.create_all()


class BookForm(FlaskForm):
    book_name = StringField('Book name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    book_author = StringField("Book author name", validators=[DataRequired()])
    publication_date = DateField("Publication date", validators=[DataRequired()])
    ISBN_num = DecimalField("The ISBN-13 number", validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField("Description", validators=[DataRequired()])
    img = FileField("Image", validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg'])])
    price = FloatField("Book price", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/add', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_book():
    form = BookForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_book = Book(
            book_name=form.book_name.data,
            book_author=form.book_author.data,
            publication_date=form.publication_date.data,
            ISBN_num=form.ISBN_num.data,
            description=form.description.data,
            img=form.img.data,
            price=form.price.data
         )
        db.session.add(new_book)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('books'))
    return render_template('add.html', form=form)


@app.route('/books')
def books():
    all_books = db.session.query(Book).all()
    return render_template('index.html', books=all_books)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my add.html file which let me to add item to index.html.

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block styles %}
{{ super() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
{% endblock %}


{% block title %}Add A New Book{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">

      <h1>Add a new book into the database</h1>

      {{ wtf.quick_form(form, novalidate=True) }}

      <p class="space-above"><a href="{{ url_for('books') }}">See all books</a></p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

index.html stand for collecting books data and show books in this page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Library</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>My Library</h1>
            {% if books == [] %}
            <p>Library is empty.</p>
            {% endif %}
        <ul>
            {% for book in books %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ url_for('delete', id=book.id) }}">Delete</a>
                {{book.name}} - {{book.author}} - {{book.date}} -
                {{ book.num }} - {{ book.description }} -
                {{ book.image_file }} - {{ book.price }}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    <a href="{{ url_for('add_book') }}">Add New Book</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It looks like the SQLite driver doesn't know how to convert Python `Decimal()` type. Try declaring `ISBN_num` as a string instead of decimal.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't worked but I am trying anyways to keep try. :)